# can i start another application using the broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

i just wanted to know i have created an application and installed it on my device.Is it possible to start this application by using only a broadcast receiver if so how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to open activity while your application is not running.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourClassActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
myIntent.addFlags(
      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

you can pass any data inside bundle like

```
bundle.putString("title", "from receiver");
```

Answer (score 0):

If BroadcastReceiver is listening then the Application is "running" also.
If you mean to open Activity, then

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class));
}
```

You need to register the receiver statically in manifest (from doc)

`You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation through the <receiver> tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.`
You should also specify the intent action you cant to catch

```
<receiver android:name=".YourReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: yes i mean open the activity but my application is not running

Comment: i want to run it listening to that broadcast reciever

Comment: Then you might want to register is statically (updated the answer)

Comment: so what i have understood form this if the wifi state is changed on my device it will start my app right

Comment: Yup, but then you should also add permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the broadcast you need to add a flag to start a package which isn't already running.

```
getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("MY_ACTION").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES), null);
```